# Remove TinyMCE registration message through package import

Tags: javascript, npm, tinymce

I want to build a TinyMCE React package and have used `import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';` However I get this message -

[image]

Normally, to get rid of the message, according to https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=90661000000IfUVAA0, you add the API key to the `.js.` in your `<script>` tag in your html. But I since I'm importing the package, there is no script for me to add the API key to.

Do I have to do something like `mce-notification-inner {display:none!important;}` or is there another way to get rid of the message?

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/react/

I also want to test using https://github.com/instructure-react/react-tinymce but don't know how to run the script. I tried this:

```
  componentWillMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js";
    // script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API key goes on the tag used to invoke the editor.  From the page you linked to:

```
<Editor apiKey='YOUR_API_KEY' init={{ /* your other settings */ }} />
```

Note the `apiKey` parameter on the tag - that is where you place the key.

Comment: Thank you, would you also know to implement something like https://github.com/instructure-react/react-tinymce even though it requires a script to be globally accessible?please see above for more details

Comment: That's not our component (I work for the company that makes TinyMCE).  You would need to ask them for assistance on how to use their component.

Comment: Thank you, I was asking that because I want to just use TinyMCE without having to run the <script> tag and without an apiKey. Do I have to have an apiKey in order to get rid of the message? Is there a way I can use the npm package without an API key and not get the message? I know there is a community version at https://www.tinymce.com/download/ but that is a script. I'd like to be able to import the .js so I can use it inside a react component

Comment: You can use the community product with module loaders but you have some work to do:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/

Comment: Is there a way to designate the version I want? It seems like you can do that with url params normally with a script tag, but from the docs it doesn't look like Editor takes a version prop

Comment: If you want to do that you would need to add the script tag yourself to your page.  If the react plugin sees that TinyMCE is already loaded it won't try to load the code itself.  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started-cloud/editor-plugin-version/

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of those messages by including the `tinymce.min.js` as stated here:

[**Loading TinyMCE by yourself**](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue#loading-tinymce)

> To opt out of using TinyMCE cloud you have to make TinyMCE globally
>   available yourself. This can be done either by hosting the
>   `tinymce.min.js` file by youself and adding a script tag to you HTML or,
>   if you are using a module loader, installing TinyMCE with npm.